# separate Json value with space and display two value with React native

Tags: json, react-native, split

I have a json data stocked in a variable, I display all my json values and I want to display one value separately:my current value is `"dateTrans": "2018-03-30 11:50:00"` and I would like to have two values : `"2018-03-30"` and `"11:50:00"`
I tried this :

```
const score = this.props.score;
const dateTrans = score.contenuTrans.dateTrans;
const dateTime = dateTrans.split(' ');
console.warn(dateTime);
```

how ca I fix it and display it ?

Comment: What is your current value and what would be after separated your desired text? Could you please update it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct. You just need to get values from its index.

```
const dateTrans = "2018-03-30 11:50:00";
const dateTime = dateTrans.split(' ');
const date = dateTime[0]
const time = dateTime[1]
console.warn(date);
console.warn(time);
```

It will provide two values you want.

Comment: thanks hahaha I was wrong putting {score.contenuTrans.dateTrans}
I had to put {score.dateTrans}!! thanks anyway